# Execute code when exiting Windows 8.1 App

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I'm attempting to execute some code on my Windows 8.1 app on exit, when a user drags the app down normally (not the extended hold to terminate).

In Windows 8, I used the following code to clear the app's tile on exit:-

```
    private async void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
    {
        Windows.UI.Notifications.TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Clear();
    }
```

However, this code isn't called in Windows 8.1 when the way the app terminate changes.

How do I recreate my code for Windows 8.1?

Answer (score 0):

In 8.1, the close gesture no longer kills the app. [Instead you have to hold it at the button for 1 second and when the icons flips](http://www.askvg.com/guide-how-to-close-metro-apps-permanently-in-windows-8-1/), the app is closed.

[image]

Look if the code is executed there.

Comment: It is, but that's the issue. The people using my app probably aren't going to be closing it that way.

Comment: The point is that on Windows 8.1, the close gesture does not exit your app. Your app is still running. It's just hidden from the switcher list. You will get the usual suspension messages when your app exits for real.

Comment: Is there any way to detect if the close gesture is executed? My app's a media app and the tile shows the currently playing track. There's no point having it running when the app's closed or whatever, and it should return to the default tile. Using `Unloaded` and `MediaEnded` don't seem to work either.